# Permutation matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation

I have two vectors v1 and v2. Are there any matlab function that can find permutation T matrix between v1 and v2 so that T*v1 = v2 in matlab?  Actually, I know how to find permutation matrix by hand when vectors are short. I just don't know how to find that matrix using matlab function when vectors' size is very long.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second output argument of sort to get the following:

```
function [I, PMat] = permutation_From_To(A,B)
[~,IA] = sort(A);
[~,IB] = sort(B);
I(IB) = IA;
PMat(:,I) = eye(length(A));
```

You can use it via:

```
A = rand(10,1);
B = A(randperm(10));
[I, PMat] = permutation_From_To(A,B);
%// All the following three lines will output the vector `B`.
B 
A(I) 
PMat*A
```

The version `A(I)` will be faster than `PMat*A`, so I included it even though you were only asking for the matrix version.